# How to register validator for Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-data, spring-data-rest

> There are two ways to register a Validator instance in Spring Data REST: wire it by bean name or register the validator manually. For the
>   majority of cases, the simple bean name prefix style is sufficient.
>
> In order to tell Spring Data REST you want a particular Validator
>   assigned to a particular event, prefix the bean name with the event in
>   question. For example, to validate instances of the Person class
>   before new ones are saved into the repository, you would declare an
>   instance of a Validator in your ApplicationContext with a bean
>   name of beforeCreatePersonValidator. Since the beforeCreate prefix
>   matches a known Spring Data REST event, that validator is wired to the
>   correct event.

I tried creating this bean but it doesn't register

```
@Component("beforeCreateOrderValidator")
public class BeforeCreateOrderValidator extends BaseValidator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Order.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {        
    }
}
```

But if I do manual registration it works

```
 @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener v) {
        v.addValidator("beforeCreate", new BeforeCreateOrderValidator());           
    }
```

Comment: Where does `BeforeCreateOrderValidator` reside? Is it actually picked up by `@ComponentScan`?